# Execute Linq to SQL queries on Navigation properties in Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to make `Statistics.Sum(s => s.Conversions)` linq query as `Linq to SQL` and not `Linq to Object` like in this code below. Every time when I access `TotalConversions` property, the whole `Statistics` table downloaded from database and then SUM linq executed locally. I want to do that in database server as SQL.

```
public class User : Entity
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Statistic> Statistics { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int TotalConversions
    {
        get
        {
            return Statistics.Sum(s => s.Conversions);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need a reference to the DbContext.  This is one of the costs of having the Entities be persistence-ignorant.

Then the property would look something like:

```
return db.Users.Single(s => s.Id = this.Id).Statistics.Sum(s => s.Conversions);
```

Comment: Your code works fine but can't be used in querying, I can't execute Linq to SQL query referencing to TotalConversions property but I am looking solution which could be used in both cases, accessing calculated property directly and using it in Linq to SQL. I have opened another question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47264072/sum-on-navigation-property-as-sql-query