# SUM on navigation property as Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am trying to find a solution how to execute `TotalConversions => Statistics.Sum(sum => sum.Conversions)` on database server using Linq to SQL.

The problem with current code is that `Statistics is ICollection`(IEnumerable) and not IQueryable and SUM function fetch all records from database locally and only when SUM the results. This is not solution for us because Statistics contain thousands of records.

```
public class User : Entity
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Statistic> Statistics { get; set; }
   [NotMapped]
   public int TotalConversions => Statistics.Sum(sum => sum.Conversions);
}
```

Another solution which we tried is to access `DbContext` inside Model and execute `Linq to SQL` query like this

```
[NotMapped]
public int TotalConversions
{
    get
    {
        if (_totalConversions == null)
        {
            var databaseContext = GetDbContextFromEntity(this);
            _totalConversions = databaseContext.Statistic.Where(s => s.UserId == Id).Sum(s => s.Conversions);
        }
        return (int)_totalConversions;
    }
}
```

It works fine but another problem comes here that such property can't be used inside linq query like this

```
_context.User.Where(w=>w.Id==1 && w.Id == 2).OrderBy(o=>o.TotalConversions)
```

How to perform `SUM` in calculated property inside `Model` which would be executed on database server and also could be used inside select queries. Is that possible at all with `EF`?

Comment: If you add a .ToList() between the Where and OrderBy() clause inside of the last piece of code, you will be able to use the TotalConversions function inside of your Linq.. reason being anything after the ToList() will now be Linq to Entities

Comment: @uk2k05 The order by should be performed to inside database, if you add ToList() the query becomes Enumerable and all actions after that performed locally, and now image this on ~200k records?! Just skip Where and let's say query has only OrderBy _context.User.OrderBy(o=>o.TotalConversions). This will not work because TotalConversions will not be translated to SQL by Linq to SQL provider. Using your suggestion _context.User.ToList().OrderBy(o=>o.TotalConversions) all sorting will be performed locally.

Comment: Shortly - it's not possible (unfortunately).

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, it is not possible with solutions I provided but I am 99% sure that it is possible using predicate with compilation.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do it the way you want.

Comment: The problem is not the implementation, but `[NotMapped]` attribute. Once you mark a property like that, you can't use it in L2E queries. If you don't mark it, the EF will seek for column in the db table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The problem.

```
[NotMapped]
public int TotalConversions => Statistics.Sum(sum => sum.Conversions);
```

When you mark a property as `[NotMapped]`, you're telling EF that this property **should not exist on the database level**. It will only be available in your code (i.e. when the data is in-memory, not when it is in-database).

Marking this property as `[NotMapped]` inherently precludes you from using a database operation (order by) using the `TotalConversions` property.

I see two solutions here. One is simple, the other less so.

---

### **Simple: Use the calculation in the `OrderBy` without a property.**

You've already pretty much done this in your second example, but you can do it a bit more concisely, avoiding use of a custom property.

What you want to do is this:

```
_context.User.Where(w=>w.Id==1 && w.Id == 2).OrderBy(o => o.TotalConversions)
```

You can't do this, as I mentioned. What you *can* do is:

```
_context.User.Where(w=>w.Id==1 && w.Id == 2).OrderBy(o => o.Statistics.Sum(sum => sum.Conversions))
```

`Sum()` has an SQL equivalent, so Linq2SQL is able to convert it. Essentially, you have changed your request from "order the collection based on this .Net property" (which is impossible) to "order the collection based on this **SQL-compatible evaluation**".

---

**However**, I assume that you're trying to use a custom property in order to avoid having to copy/paste that same calculation all over your codebase. If that is your goal, I fully agree with your intentions, and that's a good enough reason to try the more complex alternative.

### More complex: define your needed `OrderBy` parameter as a custom static `User` property.

You can parametrize the `OrderBy` parameter. First things first, The `OrderBy` method is a generic method with two generic types:

```
IOrderedQueryable<A> OrderBy<A,B>(Expression<Func<A,B>> expression) { }
```

*Note: This signature is simplified for the sake of example, to show you the basic input and output of an `OrderBy` method.*

**A** is your entity type, in your current case that is `User`.

**B** is the type of your sorting argument. You're sorting by an integer, so B is `int`.
*Note: Almost always, B can be inferred by the compiler (based on the lambda method you use) and doesn't need to be declared explicitly. However, for this solution you will need to know its type.*

This means that for your current case, we know that the `OrderBy` will take a parameter of type `Expression<Func<User,int>>`. You can confirm this by hovering over your `Orderby`, IntelliSense will tell you the types of the generic parameters as they are currently defined.

Instead of defining an `int` property like this:

```
[NotMapped]
public int TotalConversions => Statistics.Sum(sum => sum.Conversions);
```

You can define an expression property like this:

```
[NotMapped]
public static Expression<Func<User,int>> TotalConversionsLambda = (user => user.Statistics.Sum(sum => sum.Conversions));
```

Notice that I made it static, because this lambda is not tied to a specific `User` object, we want to access it without relying on an existing `User`.
This is a key difference. The int property basically says "this is how you get the total conversions for **this `User`**", whereas the expression property says "this is **the method** for retrieving the total conversions for **any given `User`**". Instead of defining the *value*, we are defining the *method* that will give us the needed value.

This means that you can use this predefined lambda when you call `OrderBy`:

```
_context.User.Where(w=>w.Id==1 && w.Id == 2).OrderBy(User.TotalConversionsLambda)
```

To the compiler (and EF), this is equivalent to the solution from the simpler method and will therefore work the same way. However, this has the added benefit of defining the lambda **once** (DRY) instead of copy/pasting it everywhere in the codebase.

---

### The explanation.

Parametrizing expressions can be a bit bewildering. That was the case for me when I started using them, at least. So maybe a simpler explanation is in order.

Notice that we can swap a literal value:

```
DoSomething(5);
```

for a variable that **contains** the value:

```
int myValue = 5;
DoSomething(myValue);
```

This example uses an integer, but we can do this for any type (`string`, `bool`, ... should be obvious). This also works for reference types:

```
DoSomething(new User() { Name = "John Doe" });
```

Versus:

```
User john = new User() { Name = "John Doe" };
DoSomething(john);
```

An `Expression<>` is a bit convoluted (due to its complex generic typing and the lambda notation), but it works exactly the same:

```
DoSomething(foo => foo.BarValue);
```

Versus:

```
Expression<Func<Foo,Bar>> myValue = (foo => foo.BarValue);
DoSomething(myValue);
```

And that's all there is to it. The type is more complex, but the underlying principle is exactly the same.

---

### Edit - Small addition

You can create an additional `int` property to use **in code**.

```
[NotMapped]
public static Expression<Func<User,int>> TotalConversionsLambda = (user => user.Statistics.Sum(sum => sum.Conversions));

[NotMapped]
public int TotalConversions
{
    get
    {
        return TotalConversionsLambda.Compile().Invoke(this);
    }
}
```

Honestly, I do think that the repeated compilation of the expression may end up hurting you more performance-wise, compared to simply defining a property that works independently of the expression property:

```
[NotMapped]
public static Expression<Func<User,int>> TotalConversionsLambda = (user => user.Statistics.Sum(sum => sum.Conversions));

[NotMapped]
public int TotalConversions
{
    get
    {
        return this.Statistics.Sum(sum => sum.Conversions);
    }
}
```

The choice is yours. You can use the first one if you want to (pedantically) adhere to DRY; but the performance cost of doing so may end up hurting you more than adhering to DRY will benefit you.

I don't have the exact numbers on the performance cost of compiling an expression, and I don't know where your priorities lie (performance over DRY? DRY over performance?), so I can't make the decision for you.

Comment: "Small addition" part will not work as expected, because Statistics is navigation property, so it will either load whole collection into memory (if lazy loading is enabled) or return 0 (or maybe even throw exception).

Comment: @Evk: The small addition is based on the OP's own initial code: `public int TotalConversions => Statistics.Sum(sum => sum.Conversions)`. What you say is correct, but that comment is equally true of OP's code. In either case (mine or his), he'd need to load the  `Statistics` entities in order to calculate their sum. I didn't introduce an error, I simply ignored it, as it's not the current topic of discussion (in my answer). But your comment is a very valid point in terms of improving the code in general!

Comment: @Evk This solution will work if DbContext in accessed inside Model(look at my question, I have provided code), then no navigation property will be used. Overall this adds a lot of complexity but can be used as solution.